# Git Wrong Repository State: SAFE

Tags: git

I created a feature branch.

I did multiple local commits on the feature branch.

I pushed it to remote repository

I did a pull.

I rebased to remote master.

(That cycle may have been repeated a few times)

I did some more local commits.

I tried to rebase.

The rebase said it needed to do a merge, then made me manually merge every change I'd made back onto all the changed files.

At the end of the rebase the following message came up:

Wrong Repository State: SAFE

[image: Error popup]

A web search gave me virtually nothing to explain what this means.

So does anyone know what it means and what I need to do about it?

I don't understand why I even needed to do the merges in the first place, since no-one else had modified these specific files, and then I have no idea what this error means at the end!

Comment: The answer might be visible in the commit graph. Try `git log --all --graph --decorate`, or `gitk --all` and look for something unexpected in there. Also, can you report what `git status` says?

Comment: @joanis I don't have the git command line set up unfortunately. Properties shows "Current state: Normal" with the correct branch etc. I just closed the problem popup box and everything seems to be working fine but I'm slightly concerned as to what it could be.

Comment: Don't you have `git bash` installed? It usually comes with Git for Windows.